# serialize a base class? Can it be done my way?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a class and its base class:

```
public class MainViewModel : Input
{
    ....
}
```

I want to (de-)serialize only the properties in the Input class
to the clipboard.

So I write a method for that in the Input class and call if from 
a method in MainViewModel:

```
serializer.Serialize(stream, this);
```

, expecting "this"to refer to Input and get only Input serialized.
But "this" keeps referring to MainViewModel and the whole
MainViewModel gets serialized.

I tried this too, which also gives me MainViewModel:

```
var clone = (Input)(this as Input).MemberwiseClone();
```

It just does not split of the Input.
Can this "great idea" be done at all?

If so, how? What do I do wrong?

Or do I have to go via an extra Input instance?

Comment: Cast it. `serializer.Serialize(stream, (Input)this)`

Comment: Doesn't work, sadly. Still MainViewMode. Cast is flagged as redundant.l  .

Comment: You can always decorate the properties you don't care to output with `[XmlIgnore]`, `[JsonIgnore]` etc. Or implement `ISerializable` on your own terms.